# How to output Buffer content completely with console.log

Tags: node.js, console.log

In `nodejs`

```
console.log(new Buffer(12))
```

show

```
< Buffer 00 22 33 11 55 ...>
```

We know the `...` ignore the following bytes. Now I want to output the whole buffer with 12 bytes, what should I do?

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`toString('hex')` works great! My example splits every 2 characters for easier visual parsing.

```
buf.toString('hex').match(/../g).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 5):

Proposal 1:

```
var buff = new Buffer(120);

var str = '';
for (var ii = 0; ii < buff.length; ii++) {
    str += buff[ii].toString(16) + ' ' ;
};
console.log(str);
```

Proposal 2:

```
console.log((new Buffer(120)).toString('hex'))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
buffer.toString('hex').replace(/(.)(.)/g, '$1$2 ')
```

Works great for me.